# ios7 setBackButtonBackgroundImage image is still stretched

Tags: ios

Using the following code to set a global navigation back button image:

```
float imageSize = 21.5; // @2x is 43px width

UIImage *barBackBtnImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-back-white"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, imageSize, 0, 0)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:barBackBtnImg
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60)
                                                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Original image: http://cl.ly/XJgD and
in-app (being stretched): http://cl.ly/XKc0

Any ideas why the image is still being stretched?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If anyone is interested, this was my fix:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-back-white"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-back-white"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: I had to use direct assignment of parameters, like this:  UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "btn-back"); UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "btn-back"); UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blackColor();

Comment: Good Solution. Thanks